# Postgis st_intersects unexpected results

Tags: postgis, postgresql, st-intersects

Trying to update one table of parcels with st_intersects from another.
Results always update all table records and don't discriminate using st_intersects.
Aim of query is to update road_class value with 1 for parcels closer than 100 meters to roads and with 2 for parcels between 100 and 800 meters of roads.
Distance selections like st_dwithin gives very slow queries.

Results of this queries are always to all parcels get same value and results doesn't discriminate for being overlayed or not.

What's wrong?

Both geometries uses same srid, 4326

And Postgresql versions are:
-PostgreSQL 10.0, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit
-POSTGIS="2.4.0 r15853" PGSQL="100" GEOS="3.6.2-CAPI-1.10.2 4d2925d" PROJ="Rel. 4.9.3, 15 August 2016" GDAL="GDAL 2.2.2, released 2017/09/15" LIBXML="2.7.8" LIBJSON="0.12" LIBPROTOBUF="1.2.1" RASTER

```
UPDATE parcels  
SET  
road_class=2  
FROM parcels p INNER JOIN road2 r ON   
st_intersects(p.geom,r.geom);  

UPDATE parcels  
SET  
road_class=1  
FROM parcels p INNER JOIN mi.r1 r ON   
st_intersects(p.geom,r.geom);  

Same results with:  
FROM parcels p,r1 r   
WHERE  
st_intersects(p.geom,r.geom);
```

Screenshot:
parcels in brown.

r1 is diagonal polygon -road buffer of 100 m.

r2 is disgonal cross pattern -road buffer since 800 meters-.

Selected parcel should get value 2, rest value 1

[image: layers]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your update query logic is not as you intended. The `SET` operation has no (implicit or explicit) `WHERE` condition to select different values. You are simply setting '1' (as a constant), as the return value of the (useless) `FROM ...` statement.
To get different values based on that condition, you could do something like this (don´t forget to fill in the `<unique_id>` both in the `WITH` query and in the `CASE` statement):

```
WITH 
  type_1 AS (
    SELECT p.<unique_id>
    FROM parcels AS p
    JOIN roads1 AS r1
      ON ST_Intersects(p.geom, r1.geom)
  )

UPDATE parcels
SET road_class = (
    CASE
      WHEN parcels.<unique_id> IN (TABLE type_1)
      THEN 1
      ELSE 2
    END
)
```

Getting all *unique_id*s of rows that intersect with a road buffer of 100m in the `WITH` query into a 'list' (*type_1* table) and check for each row in the *parcels* table if it's *unique_id* is in that list; if so, set to '1', if  not set to '2'.

I wrote this out of my head and haven´t tested. There might be more efficient solutions, but this should do the job.

Comment: Basically this solves my issue since allow me to advance.

Comment: Otherwise, complete logic is more complex since results can be 1,2, or null. But for this I can add a new WITH subselect to mention into CASE statement separated by ,

Comment: @FerranFerrer yes you can do *CASE WHEN... THEN... WHEN... THEN... ELSE... END*. add additional *tmp AS (SELECT...)* statements in the *WITH* block seperated by ','

Comment: @FerranFerrer oh and consider *accepting* an answer if it helped you as expected (I saw you answered your own question: you can accept your own answers as well). as I said, there might be other solutions, maybe someone else comes u with a faster one...but just saying ,)

Comment: Sorry, just add a +1 and forgot to accept it. ;-)

Comment: Going further, I want to do a calculus in THEN part, I use:

Comment: WITH
  type_2 AS (
    SELECT w.parcel_id,w.acreagetot,w.acreage_wetland
    FROM mi.bay_mi0 AS p, mi.wl AS w
      WHERE ST_Intersects(p.geom, w.geom))
UPDATE mi.bay_mi0
SET acreage_dry = (
    CASE
      WHEN mi.bay_mi0.parcel_id IN (TABLE type_2)
      THEN (acreagetot - acreage_wetland)
      ELSE NULL
    END
); @ThingumaBob

Comment: But planner says: 'subquery has too many fields'

Comment: @FerranFerrer mmh...this is a somewhat different task than your initial question and could be solved with different approaches. it would make sense to ask this in a new question to get a feeling for why this differs, and at least because comments are not the place to arbitrarily extend the initial question. you **could** try *...THEN (SELECT acreagetot - acreage_wetland FROM type_2 WHERE mi.bay_mi0.parcel_id = type_2.parcel_id) ...* in your new query (I´m not sure if this actually works due to the referencing to the *SET* row), **but** this adds unnecessary overhead for this specific task!

Comment: @FerranFerrer excellent...and I might be there to answer it if I have the time ,)

Comment: just added question